# Is it standard/good practice to put datasheets and/or documentation in a Git repository?

Tags: git, repository

I am currently working with a microcontroller, and in the comments of its firmware, I am linking sections of the microcontroller's datasheet for reference. Is it okay to include a copy of the datasheet in the Git repository for the project, or should I just state which version I am using in the README and leave it up to the reader to acquire for themself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add any documentation to the project repository.

I suggest you to rely on **Git LFS** for large binary files.

As stated by the [**Debugging Application**](https://books.google.it/books/about/Debugging_Applications.html?id=6b9QAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y) book, published by **Microsoft Press** in 2000, a project repository, in order to fully reproduce any release of the software, should store:

1. Source code
2. Documentation
3. Compiling toolchain
4. Operating System